# End of References

Tags: lyx, natbib

At the end of my bibliography the below is being shown. Does anyone knows how i can remove it please?

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Sorry did not understand the question? Do you you want to know what I am doing in lyx?

Comment: Please consider adding as much detail as possible to your question: What bibliography package do you use? What bibliography style? How do you cite your entries? How did you produce the bibliography etc. etc. I know you use LyX and so preparing an MWE might be harder than for the average LaTeX user, but please try to give us more than just a picture. Given the difficulties you have with LyX you should seriously consider ditching it and using normal LaTeX. It might have a steep learning curve, but it is worth it in the end (especially if you have to debug problems like these).

Comment: See also https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4488/35864

Comment: @moewe - I can't use latex as lyx was requested by my professor. I use the Natbib (bibtex) with Author - number as variance and as a bibliography style I am using "plainnat". I use JabRef to produce my bibliographies. i apologies for giving you very few information I will make it more clear next times.

Comment: OK, I have retagged your question, please try to use the correct tags in the future (you are not using `biblatex`, you are using `natbib`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864). If you must use LyX please follow the two links above to find out how to give us meaningful help instead of just screenshots.

Comment: @moewe - OK i will keep that in mind, apologies for any inconvenience

Comment: It looks like you have a whole bunch of `\cite` instructions tucked away somewhere. Not having access to your document, I'm afraid I can't offer any suggestions for *where* to start looking for these `\cite` instructions.

Comment: As Mico says, looks like you've simply cited all the stuff in your bibliography right after the bibliography. So you shouldn't really be surprised, by default citations do of course show up in the document. Try right clicking the citation(s) and select *Add to bibliography only*.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - thank you it worked when to Add to bibliography only :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citations are of course added to the document by default. That is after all the way one points to an entry in the bibliography, with a citation. As you've added a bunch of citations after the bibliography, they show up there, as expected.

If you want to add something to the bibliography without generating a citation in the document, you need to set the citation style to *Add to bibliography only*. For existing citations, this is available via the right-click context menu:

[image]

(In LaTeX terms this changes from `\cite` or similar to `\nocite`.)